# Что здесь не правильно?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$file="cena1.txt";
$open=fopen($file,"r");
$read=fread($open,filesize(cena1.txt));
fclose($open);
echo $read;
?>
```

Все равно ничего не получается... Вот посмотрите [страницу](http://prodimport.pro/tovari.php) на сайте.

Comment: Быть может такой адрес до файла исп-ть : ./cena1.txt хотя навряд ли сработает, какую то ошибку быть может выдаёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$file="cena1.txt";
$open=fopen($file,"r");
$read=fread($open,filesize("cena1.txt"));
fclose($open);
echo $read;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fclose($open);`
`filesize('cena1.txt')` или `filesize($file)`

Comment: Исправьте, что я написал.

Answer (score 1):

fclose=($open); заменить на fclose($open);